# Special characters in filename affecting aws-sdk ruby gem url_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I am using the official AWS ruby gem for S3 and I am having trouble using the "url_for" method on files that have special characters in them (ie. commas, apostrophes). I am using the latest aws-sdk gem for ruby and my code looks like this:

```
s3 = AWS::S3::new
bucket = s3.buckets[bucket]
object = bucket.objects[object_address]
object_url = object.url_for(:read, :expires => 60*60, :secure => true)
```

The object is getting found correctly, but the URL I get from url_for gives me a HTTPError: 404 Not Found error. It works fine if the filename doesn't have commas or apostrophes in it.

Is there a way to handle this without needing to restrict the filenames in the first place?

Comment: What does your URL look like?

Comment: I have replaced a few parts for privacy, but this is the gist of it.  It starts with https also...  //mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/mypathstuff/test%2Ctest.png?AWSAccessKeyId=MYACCESSKEY&Expires=1323005992&Signature=lettersandnumbers%2Bt2RtdCnBAA%3D

Comment: Above the parts I replaced were "mybucket", "mypathstuff" and "lettersandnumbers".  I have tried encoding/decoding the URL to no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Are you escaping the URL string by default?  For example:

```
object_url =  CGI.escape(object.url_for(:read, :expires => 60*60, :secure => true))
```

This would properly escape the string into a browser-readable format.  I do this for all of my secure S3 URL's since there are sometimes a `/` or `+` character in the signature that will cause the link to fail as well if it's not properly escaped.  This will also escape the commas and apostrophes properly.

Comment: I have tried with and without escaping, it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Is the `url_for` method throwing an exception (HTTPError) or is it just when you try to click the link that it's showing you a 404 page?

Comment: It's when I click the link that I get the 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue recently.  I was unable to fix filenames *before* submission so instead of using `#url_for`, I ended up writing my own encoder.  It was not too difficult, though annoying that it doesn't quite work in the `aws-sdk` gem.

Here's my solution

```
def url_for_read(path, opts)
  expire_date = (Time.zone.now + opts[:expires]).to_i
  request_string = "GET\n\n\n#{expire_date}\n/#{config[:bucket]}/#{path}"
  hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, config[:secret_access_key], request_string)
  signature = URI.escape(Base64.encode64(hmac).strip)
  s3_url_domain + "#{path}?AWSAccessKeyId=#{config[:access_key_id]}&Expires=#{expire_date}&Signature=#{CGI::escape(signature)}"
end
```

This assumes you have your aws info in a `config` hash, `digest` here is a 'sha1' and the domain looks like `https://<my_bucket>.s3-<region>.amazonaws.com`.  For the full class, you can check out this gist https://gist.github.com/bunnymatic/9274108 .

Comment: In my case, the `<StringToSign>` was expecting 2 new lines (not 3), following the content type. The response from the AWS servers is pretty helpful in this case, also, I had to URL encode the filename too.